# Conditional Istio EnvoyFilter based on Cookie presence

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, istio-gateway

Currently we're using an EnvoyFilter to add an authentication check. This filter makes use of the envoy `ext_authz` filter.

We have a GraphQL endpoint that is used for both anonymus and authorised calls. Since the public calls don't need an auth check/filter I would like to be able to skip this filter based on a cookie. I tried searching for a solution online but wasn't able to find one.

See the configuration for the filter below:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: oathkeeper
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
              subFilter:
                name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.ext_authz
          typed_config:
            '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthz
            failure_mode_allow: false
            http_service:
              path_prefix: /decisions
              server_uri:
                uri: http://oathkeeper-api.default.svc.cluster.local:4456
                cluster: outbound|4456||oathkeeper-api.default.svc.cluster.local
                timeout: 10s
              authorization_request:
                allowed_headers:
                  patterns:
                  - exact: accept
                  - exact: authorization
                  - exact: cookie
                  - exact: content-type
                  - exact: x-forwarded-for
                  - exact: x-forwarded-proto
                  - exact: x-forwarded-host
              authorization_response:
                allowed_upstream_headers:
                  patterns:
                  - exact: authorization
```

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a second `VirtualService` route for the endpoint that matches on missing cookie

```
[...]
  http:
  - name: secured-graph-ql-endpoint
    match:
    - headers:
        cookie:
          regex: <some-regex>
      uri:
        prefix: /graph-ql-endpoint
    route:
    - destination:
        host: graph-ql-endpoint
        port:
          number: 8000
  - name: public-graph-ql-endpoint
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /graph-ql-endpoint
    route:
    - destination:
        host: graph-ql-endpoint
        port:
          number: 8000
```

with a regex (`<some-regex>`) depending on your cookie. You could also have a header like `authenticated: true` and match on that, instead of a (missing) cookie.

Create an `EnvoyFilter` to disable the `ExtAuthz` for that route.

```yaml
apiVersion​: ​networking.istio.io/v1alpha3 
kind​: ​EnvoyFilter 
metadata​: 
 ​ name​: bypass-ext-authz 
 ​ namespace​: ​istio-system 
spec​: 
  workloadSelector​: 
 ​   labels​: 
 ​     istio​: ​ingressgateway 
 ​ configPatches​: 
 ​  - ​applyTo​: ​HTTP_ROUTE 
 ​    ​match​: 
 ​      ​routeConfiguration​: 
 ​        vhost​: 
 ​          route​: 
 ​            #​from virtual service http route name 
 ​            name​: public-graph-ql-endpoint
 ​    ​patch​: 
 ​      ​operation​: ​MERGE 
 ​      ​value​: 
         ​name​: ​custom.bypass_extauthz 
 ​        ​typed_per_filter_config​: 
 ​          ​envoy.ext_authz​: 
 ​            ​"​@type​"​: ​type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthzPerRoute 
 ​            ​disabled​: ​true
```

You could also add the `configPatch` to your existing `EnvoyFilter`.

Having said that:

From a design/security perspective I would rather have a different application that is publicly exposed and that queries the secured GraphQL endpoint for the anonymous user. That gives you much more control over traffic like rate limiting for external user, easier dos protection, etc.

Comment: Heey Chris thanks for your answer. What I'm missing in the answer is seeing how I could route based on a missing cookie?

The second thing doesn't really make sense to me, cause GraphQL works via a single endpoint. Which is used for both public and private calls. I just want to skip the auth check when a cookie or header is missing. Then the GraphQL service judges if the query needs authorization or not.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to route on the presence/absence of the cookie. Regarding the second point: What I am saying is that you rather should not expose an endpoint for authenticated and unauthenticated users on the same service. You could for example prevent that by adding a second endpoint for unauthenticated users as a proxy that queries the authenticated to prevent that. But that's just a side note.